# Unable to clear terminal when using jupyter console

Tags: ipython, jupyter, jupyter-console

When using the jupyter console through terminal (either directly from cmd/hyper or from notebook) the clear command (and similars) outputs some emoji-like character. I can not seem to find any known issue/bug that might link up to this. Tried fresh install, but problem persists.
CLS command works as expected in cmd.

Please see terminal print below:

```
C:\Users\kritjo>jupyter console
Jupyter console 6.2.0

Python 3.8.6 (tags/v3.8.6:db45529, Sep 23 2020, 15:52:53) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.18.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: ! CLS
♀

In [2]: clear
♀

In [3]: %clear
♀
```

[Terminal output PrtSc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUAoY.png)

OS: Win10

Any sugestions as to what might cause this issue?

Comment: Does `Ctrl+L` work?

Comment: @CasperDijkstra Yes actually does! I did not think of that, thank you. I would still like to understand why the problem occurs, but your solution is a good workaround.

Comment: Are you sure `clear` is supposed to work? I cannot find in anywhere in the documentation.

Comment: @CasperDijkstra It might be an iPython / ZeroMQ function rather than Jupyter actually; [ipython documentation, see class IPython.kernel.zmq.zmqshell.KernelMagics -> clear](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/api/generated/IPython.kernel.zmq.zmqshell.html).

Comment: Can confirm this works correctly on MacOS - appears to be a bug with Windows. I'd post an issue. Probably here: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues